# Book to learn Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have studied  real analysis from  Baby Rudin and Bartle. I find a lot of difficulty in tackling integration problems, especially when integration is mixed with sequences and series of functions, and also ones that deal with functions more complicated than the usual trignometric or polynomial ones. Although I understand the integration theorems and their proofs presented in Baby Rudin, I am unable to solve integration problems on my own. 
Can I get analysis book suggestions that can help me with integration problem solving?

Answer (score 4):

How to integrate it, by Stewart maybe?